# Turn java line comments into block comments automatically

Tags: java, eclipse, vim, comments

I have a bunch of java files with multiple sequences of line comments:

```
// blah blah blah
// blah blah blah 
// blah blah blah
```

which I want to convert into block comments with the extra opening and ending line:

```
/**
 * blah blah blah 
 * blah blah blah 
 * blah blah blah 
 */
```

Is there any easy way to it automatically for all of the comments? Preferably with `Vim` or `Eclipse`?
Sure I can write my own script, but I hope there is an easier solution.

Answer (score 2):

For **Vim**, you could easily do this with a more-or-less complex macro (depending on how robust it should be, whether it needs to support normal mode with count, visual mode, or even auto-ranging the existing comments).

But there are several commenter plugins that do this very well, and those are generic (and often extensible) so that they work for any filetype:

- [NERD Commenter plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218)
- [tComment plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1173)
- [commentary.vim plugin](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3695)

With the first plugin, you need to apply two mappings: First `3<Leader>cu` to uncomment (3 lines), then `3<Leader>cs` to use the "sexy" multi part comment delimiters. This will almost give you what you want; you just have to insert another `*` for the JavaDoc comments:

```
/*
 * blah blah blah
 * blah blah blah 
 * blah blah blah
 */
```

#### automation

To locate subsequent lines of line comments (assumption here is starting in the first column), you can use `:help :range`. Make the range start with the next commented line, and have it continue until the next line that does not start with a line comment, or is empty. To develop this, using the `:print` command is handy:

```
:/^\/\/ /;/\%(^$\|^[^\/]\)/-1print
```

Once this works, we can trigger the *uncomment* mapping (via `:normal`):

```
:/^\/\/ /;/\%(^$\|^[^\/]\)/-1normal \cu
```

This uncommented each line separately; for the (block) commenting, we need to process the block as a whole, passing a `[count]` to the mapping. Fortunately, the *change marks* now delimit the whole uncommented block, so we can use them to:

- navigate back to the start
- calculate the number of subsequent lines
- trigger the *sexy comment* mapping

```
:execute line("'[") | execute 'normal' (line("']") - line("'[") + 1) . '\cs'
```

If it were not for the last step, the change could be applied to the entire file via `:global`. Instead, you need to repeatedly trigger the above steps until the end of the buffer is reached. A *recursive macro* can do this for you. Then, you could apply that macro over multiple files via either `:bufdo` or `:argdo`. But you'd have to be pretty sure that the macro is robust and does not wreak havoc on some corner cases. So, this is a trade-off depending on the number of occurrences that you face.

Comment: Thanks. Yet (for my understanding), I will need to go over each file, find the comments, count the lines etc. I would wish to avoid that.

Comment: Well, Vim can help with iteration (`:bufdo`, `:argdo`), locating (`:/`, `:call search()`), and so on. Depending on the number of files (and whether this is a one-off task or done frequently) and your proficiency in Vim, you can automate this partially or completely.

Comment: Yeah, perhaps that is the way as it is a one-off task. The main issue for me is how to connect sequentially comment lines in my vim actions.

Comment: I've expanded my answer with the outline of automation steps. Depending on your Vim knowledge, either you can take it from there, or decide that it's too involved, and do this manually, or keep searching for another tool.

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is an easy way. You can use the following shortcuts...

Ctrl + /
Add/**Remove** line comments (//…) from the current line.

Ctrl + Shift + /
Wrap the selected lines in a block comment (/*… */).

Comment: Thanks. I will still need to go over each file, find the comments, select them etc. I would wish to avoid that and do it automatically for all of the comments.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse you can do this by:
Selecting lines to comment and `Ctrl + Shift + /` - (generate block line comment)

`Ctrl + Shift + F` (run eclipse formatter).
running eclipse formatter will add `*` on each line of comment.

To remove comments, `Ctrl + Shift + \`

Comment: Thanks. But, as I said, I would like to do it automatically for all of the comments.

Answer (score -1):

You can select multiple lines and press `Ctrl + /` for place `/` at all lines.